# Dictionary With Multiple Values To Nested List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{'ONE' : (4, 6, 9), 'TWO' : (3, 8, 10)}
```

I'd like to sort this dictionary by the 3rd value of each tuple. I can't really think of a way to accomplish this with the data setup as a dictionary, but it should be fairly easy if I can convert the data to a nested list like the following:

```
[['ONE', 4, 6, 9], ['TWO', 3, 8, 10]]
```

I'm looking for the most efficient code for accomplishing this. If there is a way to sort this dictionary without converting it, that would be ideal. If not, any assistance with the conversion from dictionary to nested list would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's no concept of order for dictionaries, so you cannot sort them. You need to do it in an indirect way, such the one you're suggesting.

Comment: actually, python 2.7 has the [OrderedDict class](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: But they remember only the order in which the keys have been entered. You still need some trick to sort the data (and create a new `OrderedDict` in the process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `key` argument of the built-in `sorted` function:

```
>>> d = {'ONE' : (4, 6, 9), 'TWO' : (3, 8, 10), 'FOUR': (2, 5, 8)}
>>> sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1][2])
[('FOUR', (2, 5, 8)), ('ONE', (4, 6, 9)), ('TWO', (3, 8, 10))]
```

**EDIT**

If some of the values are ints rather than tuples, then something like this should work:

```
>>> d = {'ONE' : (4, 6, 9), 'TWO' : (3, 8, 10), 'FOUR': (2, 5, 8), 'THREE': 0}
>>> sorted(d.iteritems(),
...        key=lambda i: i[1][2] if isinstance(i[1], tuple) else i[1])
[('THREE', 0), ('FOUR', (2, 5, 8)), ('ONE', (4, 6, 9)), ('TWO', (3, 8, 10))]
```

However, in the long run, it's probably better to normalize the data so that the values all have the same format.

Comment: You guys are all fantastic. This is great, while all of the suggestions were very useful, I think this is the simplest way (after i remove the ints)

Comment: @PatrickD. I've updated my answer with a version that copes with ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
nestedlist = [[key] + list(value) for key,value in dictionary.items() if value != 0]
```

Comment: I get an 'int' not iterable error. My actual dictionary is pretty massive, with a string as a key, and three floats in a tuple for each value. Actual example:

'REPUBLIC OF BRAZIL' : (0.013454, 0.005123, 0.008417369999)

Comment: @PatrickD, is it possible one of your values in your dictionary isn't a tuple but an int? That would explain the error you get.

Comment: Sounds like what @RobWouters says, yeah.

Comment: Ah, yes, looking through the dictionary, there are values that are 0 instead of a tuple. Any workaround suggestions?

Comment: Depends on what would you want to have those entries translated into :)

Comment: Haha, well I suppose I could just remove them from the dictionary since I don't really need to retain zero values. I'll give that a try. Thanks to both of you for your help!

Comment: @PatrickD: I've edited the answer to create the list only where the value is not 0. No need to touch the dictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
result = []
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    result.append([key] + list(value))
```

If some of your values are of type `int` instead of tuples try this:

```
result = []
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    try:
        lst = list(value)
    except TypeError:
        lst = [value]
    result.append([key] + lst)
```

Comment: This gives him a list which contains non-regular elements. Having that he intends to sort by the 3rd value from each tuple... this will not fail when translating the dictionary to a list, but will later when sorting.